# An error in the creation of canvas by Javascript elements

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to Create a canvas with only JavaScript Eléments 
But I found an error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

My Javascript code is  :

```
   // create the canvas on the page : 
var myPageCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");

  // Assigne Id to thin canvas  :         
myPageCanvas.id = 'c';

 // custumize canvas  :     
myPageCanvas.height = 300;
myPageCanvas.width = 500;
myPageCanvas.style.display = "block";
myPageCanvas.style.margin = "50px auto";

// Add the canvas on the page : 
document.body.appendChild(myPageCanvas);
```

Comment: DId you copy and paste your code, or you rewrote it?. I do not see any problem in your code.

Comment: When I used google Chrome's console , says that's Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null , My code is on question =)

Comment: your pages seemingly does contain a <body> element or you did not close </body> tag.

Comment: javascript calling function are empty

Comment: @prasad Possible explain more ?

Comment: @Abdallah.BeraYda in your question doesn't any possibility of the triggering the append event.See the below answer he was applied with click event.The `canvas` append at the time of click.so you should apply your any one of the JavaScript function.otherwise it will not run. more explanation ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Click the button to append canvas.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Append</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var myPageCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");

  // Assigne Id to thin canvas  :         
myPageCanvas.id = 'c';

 // custumize canvas  :     
myPageCanvas.height = 300;
myPageCanvas.width = 500;
myPageCanvas.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
myPageCanvas.style.display = "block";
myPageCanvas.style.margin = "50px auto";

// Add the canvas on the page : 
document.body.appendChild(myPageCanvas);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Complete working code

Comment: most welcome :) There was no problem with the code you posted. I guess there was some problem with syntax or something that you did not posted. So I wrote complete code.

Comment: The problem is that the JS code executes before the window is loaded so your answer only indirectly solves the problem by executing the code on a button push. Blindman67's answer is more direct and therefore more generally usable.

Comment: You are right, thanks for clearing my misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 2):

You are likely running the script before the document.body has been created.

Either put the script in the body tag, or use `document.addEventListener("load",function(){ your script })` so that the code runs when the page has loaded and the body element created